# VBA Code in Module and Assigned Macro to Button or Text box Giving Different Results

Tags: excel, vba, countif

VBA code in Module is working Fine but When Macro is assigned to either Text Box, or Activex Control Button or Form Control Button - then the Result is Incorrect

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim w As Long

    w = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("R1:R5186"), Range("$W$2"))

    If w < "433" Then

    sh.Range("W3:W" & w + 2).Value = 1

    End If

End Sub
```

Further, when this code is Entered in Data Form Command Button Click, the result is incorrect the code is correctly working only in Module while running through F5 or F8.

Comment: qualify your `Range` objects up to `Worksheet` object (e.g.: `Range("R1:R5186")` becomes `sh.Range("R1:R5186")`, and the likes)

Comment: furthermore, although not apparently related to your issue, you'd better be consistent with data types you declared, hence change `If w < "433"` to `If w < 433`